# C: Post json data using HTTP requests

Tags: c, json, http, curl, post

I am trying to post json data to a server through an URL using C. I have downloaded the curl.h package from `https://curl.se/download.html` and has included it in the code. This is what I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "F:\Desktop\myfolder\curl\include\curl\curl.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL) {
        return 128;
    }

    char* jsonObj = "{ \"name\" : \"ABC\" , \"age\" : \"22\" }";

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
    curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    curl_slist_append(headers, "charset: utf-8");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip-address/myapi/");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, jsonObj);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcrp/0.1");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return res;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x136): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_slist_append'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x1e8): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x209): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x219): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoDiLJ0.o:gpsapi.c:(.text+0x235): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is this the right way to do it or am I missing something? I am quite new to sending requests in C, so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How do you build your code? Did you know how to link to a library?

Comment: @Mathieu, I ran the code using gcc filename.c. Is there any other library that I should import in the code?

Comment: I guess `gcc filename.c -L/path/to/libcurl -lcurl`

Comment: I did this, but I am getting the error:
`C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: A header file is just a list of all the stuff in the library. It's not the actual library. You need the actual library as well.

Comment: Which package you download and how you install it is not clear. If you just download the source package, you need to build it, if you download a binary package, you need to install it...

Comment: I downloaded the zip file of curl package, extracted it, and used the curl.h as the header file.